# Nginx -> Apache commands

Tags: apache, nginx, apache2

How is it possible to write these into Apache conf file?

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_read_timeout 200;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

I want to run a site, but in the manual they gave me that NGINX code, but my hosting only allows me Apache2. Is it possible to do it anyway? Or i can throw it into the garbage?

Answer (score 1):

You should be trying to get Apache working with FastCGI so you may follow [this](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/apache/running-fastcgi-php-fpm-on-debian-7-with-apache/) guide, which boiled down requires you to:

Type `sudo a2enmod actions`

Type `sudo grep -E '^\s*listen\s*=\s*[a-zA-Z/]+' /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

See `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`

```
or if you don't, add "listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock" and remove "listen = 127.0.0.1:9000" (without quotes) from /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

Edit your `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fastcgi.conf` file and change it to be like this.

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>  
    AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp5 .php 
    Action application/x-httpd-fastphp5 /php5-fcgi  Alias /php5-fcgi
    /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi  FastCgiExternalServer
    FastCgiConfig -appConnTimeout 60 -singleThreshold 100 -killInterval 300 -idle-timeout 180  -maxClassProcesses 1 -pass-header HTTP_AUTHORIZATION
    /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization  
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>   
     Require all granted 
    </Directory> 
</IfModule>
```

I've added your rules to this file so feel free to look and see on what it is. [This](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/q20204/mod_fastcgi.html#FastCgiConfig) is a document detailing what you can add to your FastCGI in case you wanted anything else.

Run `sudo apache2ctl configtest`

Run `sudo service apache2 restart`

Run `sudo echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/info.php` and navigate to `yoursitenameorIP/info.php` and see if everything is working (specifically check to see if you see FastCGI enabled), then run `sudo rm /var/www/info.php` and continue with your guide.